# Custom calendar view своими руками

Tags: android, customview, android-customview, calendar-view

Хочу сделать свою собственную вьюшку с календарем. В чем ее отличие от обычного. Она должна уметь сворачиваться в горизонтальный и разворачиваться в обычный. Я видел библиотеки, позволяющие сделать подобное, но я хочу сделать именно свою вьюшку. Задача не получить хорошую вью, которую можно будет использовать в проектах и т.п., а научиться делать подобное.

Comment: Боюсь здесь обсуждают конкретные вопросы, а не личностные стартапы :) Можно посоветовать поизучать код этих библиотек и оттуда почерпнуть что-то, а с конкретными проблемами/вопросами - welcome!

Comment: Можете почитать [тут](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want), подробно описано

Comment: @DevOma Непередаваемо благодарен за помощь!